# Error Calling .NET webservice - {ClassName} not found in the specified assembly list

Tags: coldfusion

I have a .NET service which I need to call from ColdFusion. The service requires me to pass an object as a parameter. When I dump the service the output looks like this:

[image: Web Service Dump]

The code I am using to call the service is:

```
<cfset employeenumbers = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset employeenumbers[1] = "152786">
<cfset employeenumbers[2] = "210562">
<cfset employeenumbers[3] = "200788">
<cfset context = createObject(".NET","com.microsoft.schemas.dynamics._2010._01.datacontracts.CallContextE")>
<cfset context.Company = 'US03'>

<cfinvoke webservice="http://050-aos-08.tubecityims.com:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/TCCWorkerPayDecryptService?wsdl" method="empPayList" returnvariable="answer" refreshwsdl="true">
    <cfinvokeargument name="CallContextE" value="#context#">
    <cfinvokeargument name="_empList" value="#employeenumbers#">
</cfinvoke>
<cfoutput>#answer#</cfoutput>
```

The errror I am getting is:

> Class
>   com.microsoft.schemas.dynamics._2010._01.datacontracts.CallContextE
>   not found in the specified assembly list.

**Update:**

This is the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:operation name="empPayList"> 
   <soap12:operation soapAction="tempuri.org/TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptService/empPay‌​List"; style="document"/> 
   <wsdl:input name="TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListRequest">
   <soap12:header message="i0:TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListRequest_H‌​eaders" part="context" use="literal"/> 
   <soap12:body use="literal"/> 
</wsdl:input> 
<wsdl:output name="TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListResponse">
    <soap12:body use="literal"/> 
</wsdl:output>
```

Comment: 1. CreateObject(".net") uses *dlls* on the CF server. Obviously there is no dll file on your server containing that class, hence the error. 2. Also, web services - even .net web services - are invoked using java classes. You cannot mix the two. Can you post the wsdl for that method and the CallContextE type?

Comment: <wsdl:operation name="empPayList">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptService/empPayList" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListRequest">
<soap12:header message="i0:TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListRequest_Headers" part="context" use="literal"/>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="TCCWorkerSalaryDecryptServiceEmpPayListResponse">
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>

Comment: No, look for the method definition which includes the parameters, ie array of strings and CallContextE.  Also, the definition of CallContextE which tells you what type of object it is ..

Comment: I made a few changes to the code

Comment: <cfset employeenumbers = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset employeenumbers[1] = "152486">
<cfset employeenumbers[2] = "210982">
<cfset employeenumbers[3] = "200548">


<cfset objectTest = createObject(".net", "HcmWorkerPayDecrypt.TCCDecrypt", "HcmWorkerPayDecrypt.dll")>

<cfdump var="#objectTest#">


<cfset salaryList = objectTest.payList(#employeeNumbers#,'US05')>

Comment: I can see the Class and its methods when I dump the object
object of HcmWorkerPayDecrypt.TCCDecrypt
Class Name HcmWorkerPayDecrypt.TCCDecrypt
Methods 
Method Return Type
payList(java.lang.String[], java.lang.String) System.Decimal[]

But when I dump the SalaryList I get an error ...

Comment: Thank you for your help Leigh ...it finally worked. The issue was with the .DLL.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Out of curiosity, are you using *both* a web service and a DLL? Did not think that was allowed :) Also, if you think the solution might be helpful to someone else, please write it up as an "answer". (Answering your own question is allowed on S.O.)